# TypeLoadException when trying to mock IObjectSet with Moq

Tags: moq, typeloadexception

I have the following setup code:

```
MockOf<IObjectSet<Dummy>>().Setup(c => c.AddObject(dummy)).Verifiable();
MockOf<IObjectContextWrapper>().Setup(c => c.GetObjectSet<Dummy>()).Returns(MockOf<IObjectSet<Dummy>>().Object);
```

where `Dummy` is an empty class definition, and `dummy` is a `Dummy`. `MockOf<T>()` is a mock managing feature on a base class, which basically makes sure that each time it's called on a type, it returns the same mock instance.

The test containing this setup code fails with a `TypeLoadException` and the following message:

> System.TypeLoadException : Type 'IObjectSet`1Proxy389e220f10aa4d9281d0b9e136edc1d4' from assembly 'DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a621a9e7e5c32e69' is attempting to implement an inaccessible interface.
>
> at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.TermCreateClass(RuntimeModule module, Int32 tk, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
>   at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateTypeNoLock()
>   at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateType()
>   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.Emitters.AbstractTypeEmitter.BuildType()
>   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.InterfaceProxyWithTargetGenerator.GenerateCode(Type proxyTargetType, Type[] interfaces, ProxyGenerationOptions options)
>   at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget(Type interfaceToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, ProxyGenerationOptions options, IInterceptor[] interceptors)
>   at Moq.Mock`1.<InitializeInstance>b__0()
>
>   at Moq.Mock`1.InitializeInstance()
>   at Moq.Mock`1.get_Object()
>   at OddEnds.Tests.Data.EntityFramework.RepositoryTest.Delete_DeletesObjectFromObjectSet() in RepositoryTest.cs: line 43

I have imported `System.Data.Objects` and referenced both System.Data.Entity.dll and Microsoft.Data.Entity.CTP.dll in both the test project and the project where the class being tested resides. The build succeeds with no errors, warnings or messages (except a few related to Code Contracts...)

**How do I fix this?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Are any of the interfaces or class you are using in your tests internal? Are you using something like `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("YourTestAssembly")]` in order to get things to compile?

If so, you'll also need to add one for DynamicProxyGenAssembly2 in order for Moq to dynamically generate the proxy for the classes.

```
//goes in the AssemblyInfo.cs where the internal interfaces / classes are defined
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]
```

Here is a relevent post about the topic

http://sonofpirate.blogspot.com/2009/09/my-first-foray-into-unit-testing-with.html

I hope this helps

Comment: I've since long stopped working on this - and the computer I was working on it with was stolen :( - so I have no way of verifying if this is a solution to the problem. If someone else comes here and finds this useful, please let me know and I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: I've been googling this problem for quite a while today. Generally this should work, this is also written on the official moq site http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart. However it did not work for me. It has to do with latest version of libraries used by moq I guess. I came over this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156499/castle-windsor-internalsvisibleto-silverlight and adding InternalsVisibleTo Castle.Core and Castle.Windsor (and DynamicProxyGenAssembly2 of course) did the trick. PS: I was mocking an internal interface

Comment: This did work in VS2017 on .Net Core 1.0. Also important, it worked as above with no Public Key included. Some other answers suggest a public key but that did not help in our case.

Answer (score 12):

I found that in my case I had created a Dummy class instance to be used in my unit test which happened to be private (as I didn't really want to share the test object outside).

My code was along these lines:

```
var mockMonitor = new Mock<ICacheMonitor<int, PrivateObject>>();
```

where the PrivateObject was a private class definition within my TestClass.
The fix in my case is therefore to ensure that any of the types in your Mock constructor are public.

```
public class PrivateObject () {}
```

(Obviously I wouldn't call my public object a PrivateObject either...)

Comment: Thanks! This is potentially very non-obvious. I thought for sure there was something wrong with the interface that I was trying to mock, but I had just forgotten to make one of my objects public.

Answer (score 0):

I tripped across another case which I couldn't figure out at first.  I was working on a proxy for an interface created inside of my unit test...

```
public IDoWork
{
    void DoWork();
}
```

It took me forever to figure out that the problem was not with that interface, but was, rather, that the unit test itself was not public:

```
class TestSomething // missing public keyword
{

// .. some test which tries to create a mock of the interface


    public IDoWork
    {
        void DoWork();
    }

}
```

So, while IDoWork is says it's public, it really is not since it's enclosed in a private class.

Hope this helps someone.